# Why Razor add another value attribute and how to remove it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

When I type the following in a razor view page:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new {@Value="Default Value", @Class = "CSSRadwan" })
```

It translated to the following:

```
 <input Class="CSSRadwan" Value="Default Value" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
```

If I change @Value with @value (small "v") it doesn't translated at all.

My questions are:

Why there is another attribute called "value" and it's empty? how to remove it?

Why the character "V" in "Value" attribute is capital and the other one is small what if I want the first one to be small too as normal attributes, how to do that?

I am using MVC4.0 and Visual Studio 2012 Update 1.

Comment: I really think that if you are using the TextBoxFor it is implicity that you want to display the model property value in the text input. Otherwise you could use the TextBox.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I want to use TextBoxFor

Comment: I think gustov is right on this. If your set on using the wrong tool then dont be surprised it gives strange results. You could always prefill your model Name value with Default Value

Comment: I was doing some research. I don't think this is possible. Maybe you should create an editor template :)

Comment: There is indeed a difference between displayfor helpers and textboxfor helpers

Comment: maybe this question are duplicate: http://goo.gl/IWL4G http://goo.gl/U3QqV http://goo.gl/v8QBP

Comment: Thanks for all of you

Answer (score 1):

> Why there is another attribute called "value" ...

If you take a look at the source code for MVC, you will see that in [System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs), the `value` attribute will *always* be set by the framework, due to the following line in the method `InputHelper`:

```
tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", attemptedValue ?? ((useViewData) ? htmlHelper.EvalString(fullName, format) : valueParameter), isExplicitValue);
```

When using `TextBoxFor`, `isExplicitValue` is `true` and the `value` attribute will thus overwrite any existing html attribute named `value`. This explains why you cannot use `new { @value="My value" }` in `TextBoxFor`.

> ... and it's empty?

Because m.Name does not have a value initially.

> how to remove it?

You cannot remove the `value` as demonstrated above.

> Why the character "V" in "Value" attribute is capital and the other one is small what if I want the first one to be small too as normal attributes, how to do that?

It has to be upper-case V in `Value` to distinguish it from lower-case `value` so it does not get overwritten by the framework as explained above. Indeed, you will get an output such as:

```
<input Value="Default Value" value="" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" />
```

Since `Value` appears before `value` in the html, "Default Value" will be rendered and shown in the textbox by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The "value" attribute of an HTML input element represents the value to be posted, or the default value if it is explicitly set. The TextBoxFor helper is designed for displaying the values from a model as gustavodidomenico points out, which is why the attribute is rendered. If you don't want a value attribute to be rendered, use the TextBox helper instead. That is the correct tool for your requirement.

The reason that your value attribute has a capital 'V' is because you specify one on your anonymous object's property name. Same thing goes for "Class". Change the property names to begin with lowercase letters:

```
new { @class = "CSSRadwan", @value = "Default Value" }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if you try the code you provide, you will find that it doesn't work, I already mention that in the question "If I change @Value with (small "v") it doesn't translated at all."

Comment: Have you tried applying the snippet to a TextBox rather than a TextBoxFor?